# go - Can't create copy of variable of type map[int]Struct in another variable by just assigning one variable to another

Tags: go

I have a Map :

```
cart := map[10033207:{10033207 3 425 126} 10012761:{10012761 4 40 0}]
```

I want to create copy of `cart` in another variable `tempCart` so that I can modify tempCart for temporary usage in my function. I want that cart value remains the same.

```
tempCart := cart
//some operation which modifies temp cart and make it
//map[10033207:{10033207 2 425 126} 10012761:{10012761 1 40 0}]
```

The problem is that when I modify `tempCart`, somehow `cart` is also getting modified and becomes `equal` to `tempCart`.

Later when I print value of `cart` I get:
`map[10033207:{10033207 2 425 126} 10012761:{10012761 1 40 0}]` and not the original value that is `map[10033207:{10033207 3 425 126} 10012761:{10012761 4 40 0}]`.

I can't understand the reason behind it and want to know the solution of how to create a copy of `cart`.

EDIT: This question has been marked as Duplicate to `copy one map to another` But I knew how to copy one map to anothor, my prime question was why couldn't I just assign one map to another variable. Why do I have to copy it in a loop.

Comment: `tempCart := cart` is just assigning the reference of one struct to another. It is not "copying". There is no in-built way to copy structs in Go. You'll have to initialize the new struct with the values from the other one manually, or use a library like https://github.com/jinzhu/copier

Comment: Can't it be done somehow using pointers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is a map value in one function affected by an entry to the map in another function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605295/why-is-a-map-value-in-one-function-affected-by-an-entry-to-the-map-in-another-fu) Also related: [Copying all elements of a map into another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7436864/copying-all-elements-of-a-map-into-another).

Comment: @Jagrati: You use pointers specifically ***to modify*** the values of the original

Comment: @icza thanks I went through the answers of those question. However, I asked this question because I didn't knew I should have searched my problem like that. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to copy a map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23057785/how-to-copy-a-map)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Copy a map use

```
for k,v := range originalMap {
  newMap[k] = v
}
```

Comment: This will not do a deep copy of the structs in the map.